# Dask - Reading partitions in order using itertuples

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm using `Dask` to read in a table with around 14 million rows using `read_sql_table`. When I read the dataframe using `itertuples` the index (which is ordered in the table) is not read out sequentially for one or two partitions. How is it possible to enforce this? The `row_id` is generated by `row_number` (on the view) and is used as the index when generating the dataframe. I know Pandas has a `sorted=True` arg, anything similar?

This is what happens at the moment, while reading the data in (number of rows read should match the current index):

 `INFO - Read 11870000 Rows (index: 11870000)
 INFO - Read 11880000 Rows (index: 11880000)
 INFO - Read 11890000 Rows (index: 11890000)
 INFO - Read 11900000 Rows (index: 11900000)
 --INFO - Read 11910000 Rows (index: 12159912)--
 INFO - Read 11920000 Rows (index: 12169912)
 INFO - Read 11930000 Rows (index: 12179912)
 INFO - Read 11940000 Rows (index: 12189912)`

All is good until the 11,900,000th row, and at that point it switches in the wrong partition.

Comment: Can you make an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Is it SQL specific?

You say `read_sql_table`, is that dask's or pandas'?

(just curios: why are you using `itertuples`? that's going to be slow for 14M records)

Comment: This is to feed in to a third party modelling tool, so there are various options (including reading the data in, altering it in some way, and writing it back to a DB). In this case I wanted to see how the performance was while just keeping it in a Dask DF. I'm not sure that an MVCE would highlight the issue, as divisions are created properly, in order, but when iterating through using itertuples (in Dask) it looks like the partitions are loaded up in a different order; but only occasionally, which makes me think the requests are parallelised to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an answer to the issue (which is perhaps rare), but the software that reads the stream requires a monotonically increasing index. I can only assume that it's the multiple calls to the DB which are being resolved at different speeds, so possibly another option would be to use the single-threaded scheduler on the `compute` call to `read_sql_table`.

First of all, I get the first index in each partition;

```
def _order_partitions(self, ddf):
    ordering = {}
    for partition in range(ddf.npartitions):
        ordering.update({partition: int(df.get_partition(partition).head(1).index[0])})

    return sorted(ordering, key=ordering.get)
```

Storing the result in `self._ordered_partitions`, and then I recreate the itertuples function call in Dask (which is quite simple);

```
def _generator(self):
    for i in range(self._ddf.npartitions):
        ordered_partition = self._ordered_partitions[i]
        df = self._ddf.get_partition(ordered_partition).compute()
        for row in df.itertuples():
            yield row
```

The only change being the addition of the `ordered_partition`. I've not fully tested it yet, so will mark as an answer once I'm happy with it.